# Rails Convert Array of Strings to Unordered List for Flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So flash notices are being displayed from a CMS we're using so when we flash the design/layout is pretty hard to get to. So anything that I flash will display in that section and the only thing I can really change is the styling. Unless I can do in the Layout > Application render flash unless this one page.

What I have is an array of strings that I'm trying to convert into an unordered list. So for example it's showing up like `@fruit = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]`.

My thought was to simply do

```
@fruit.map(&:inspect).join("\n").delete('""')
```

With the hope of getting

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange

However since it's in the flash there's no discerning line break. If I inspect sure enough it's showing multiple lines but lumped within a text.

I even went in and did the following thinking it would work:

```
-flash.each do |type, msg|
 ul
  =content_tag :li, msg, id: "flash_#{type}"
```

But its actually not breaking the msg up into an unordered list, especially within the ul, and instead doing:

```
<ul></ul>
 <li id="flash_error">"Apple Banana Orange"</li>
```

So is there a way to convert an array of strings into an unordered list for a flash message?

Comment: How are you assigning `@fruit.map(&:inspect).join("\n").delete('""')` to `flash`?

Comment: Right now its coming back from an import and coming back to the conditional to handle errors so something like flash[:error] = @fruit.map(&:inspect).join("\n").delete('""')

Comment: check my answer and change `flash[:notice]` to `flash[:error]` and i don't know why you need the `&:inspect` and `delete` but if it makes sense to you that's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flash` lets you use primitive types (`string`, `array`, `hash`, ...) but you need to handle that in the view, if you put an array in it you need to iterate that array.

```
@fruit = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
flash[:notice] = @fruit
```

(also, `ul` should be outside of `flash.each`)

```
ul
  - flash.each do |type, msg|
    - if msg.is_a? Array
      - msg.each do |a|
        = content_tag :li, a, id: "flash_#{type}"
    - else
      = content_tag :li, msg, id: "flash_#{type}"
```

Comment: If you want to be picky you also need to use a condition to avoid an empty UL element as thats invalid HTML.