# Rails Helper Handle Flash with ul

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to style a flash notice within a helper passing along an array. So something like:

```
def import
 @fruit = Fruit::Import.run(params[:food_id], params[:file]).result
 if @fruit.empty?
  flash[:notice] = 'Success'
 else
  flash_message(@fruit)
 end
end
```

I made sure to include in the controller include FoodsHelper at the top of the controller.

So within the helper I have:

```
def flash_message(fruit)
 content_tag(:ul, class: 'alert alert-error') do
  fruit.each do |type, msg|
   msg.each do |item|
    content_tag(:li, item, class: "flash_#{type}")
   end
  end
 end
end
```

The hope would have a ul and each of the elements within the array from fruit would display as a list item. This however comes up with undefined method `content_tag' did you mean content_type?

Is there a good way to iterate a flash notice with content_tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Convert Array of Strings to Unordered List for Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324592/rails-convert-array-of-strings-to-unordered-list-for-flash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324592/rails-convert-array-of-strings-to-unordered-list-for-flash) (I don't really know what you are trying to do here)

> The hope would have a ul and each of the elements within the array
>   from fruit would display as a list item. This however comes up with
>   undefined method `content_tag' did you mean content_type?

If you want to use `content_tag` from a controller you need to add this:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
```

or in Rails 5 just use `helpers.content_tag`

```
helpers.content_tag(:ul, class: 'alert alert-error') do ...
```

> Is there a good way to iterate a flash notice with content_tag?

There's no such a thing as 'iterate a flash[:notice] with content_tag'

Maybe you want to do this:

Controller:

```
def import
 @fruit = Fruit::Import.run(params[:food_id], params[:file]).result
 if @fruit.empty?
  flash[:notice] = 'Success'
 else
  flash[:notice] = @fruit
 end
end
```

Helper:

```
def flash_message
 content_tag(:ul, class: 'alert alert-error') do
  flash.each do |type, msg|
   if msg.is_a? Array
     msg.each do |item|
      content_tag(:li, item, class: "flash_#{type}")
     end
   else
    content_tag(:li, msg, class: "flash_#{type}")
   end
  end
 end
end
```

View:

```
<%= flash_message %>
```